# How to identify column data type in Redsift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Im very new to SQL so please forgive me for the basic question. I am trying to find out what the data type is for each column in a table.
Can someone please help me with the correct command? Im not able to get anything to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `PG_TABLE_DEF` which only returns information about tables that are visible to the user.

for example :

```
select "column", type, encoding, distkey, sortkey, "notnull" 
from pg_table_def
where tablename = 'lineorder_interleaved'
```

output:

| column | type | encoding | distkey | sortkey | notnull |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lo_orderkey | integer | delta32k | false | -1 | true |
| lo_custkey | integer | none | false | 2 | true |
| lo_partkey | integer | none | true | -3 | true |
| lo_suppkey | integer | delta32k | false | 4 | true |
| lo_orderdate | integer | delta | false | -5 | true |

[Database Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html)

or also you can use `PG_GET_COLS` which returns the column metadata for a table or view definition.

for example:

```
select * from pg_get_cols('sales_vw') 
cols(view_schema name, view_name name, col_name name, col_type varchar, col_num int);
```

| view_schema | view_name | col_name | col_type | col_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| public | sales_vw | salesid | integer | 1 |
| public | sales_vw | listid | integer | 2 |
| public | sales_vw | sellerid | integer | 3 |
| public | sales_vw | buyerid | integer | 4 |
| public | sales_vw | eventid | integer | 5 |
| public | sales_vw | dateid | smallint | 6 |
| public | sales_vw | qtysold | smallint | 7 |
| public | sales_vw | pricepaid | numeric(8,2) | 8 |
| public | sales_vw | commission | numeric(8,2) | 9 |
| public | sales_vw | saletime | timestamp without time zone | 10 |

[Database Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/PG_GET_COLS.html)